# GWT - open source UI lib

Tags: gwt

I am looking for an Open Source lib for GWT 2.3+ which has dynamic TabbedPane (with close tab button, scrolling, events support etc). I googled but couldn't find any. So I need your skilled advice. Is there such a lib and where to find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SmartGWT**? here is the link to the showcase of **[TabSet](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_tabs_closeable)** component. What do you mean by events? EventBus? I was using the [GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) framework for this purpose.

EDIT:
[license](http://smartclient.com/product/)

Comment: smartGWT sounds interesting... I am not pretty sure about its license... Does it allows commercial apps development?

Comment: By 'events' I mean select tab etc events swing-like listeners. Does TabSet supports setTab(index) for example?

Comment: And how to know which smartGWT version is OK for GWT SDK 2.3?

Comment: They provide all the functionality presented in the showcase under LGPL Edition for free, however, the support is limited and the delay of response on their forum is quite large if any. I don't have any experience with enterprise version. You can select (in code) any tab, you can add click or other listeners on components, so yeah, it is pretty much as swing. The version should be ok, but I am not completely sure. Now we use GWT 2.4 and SmartGWT 3.0.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. But the lib itself is pretty heavy so I must ask is there something that has less weight?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily build it as a custom widget in GWT.

You need a top panel to show your "tabs" and a panel below it to show a tab content. When a user clicks on a tab, you populate the bottom panel with a selected tab content. You can easily add a button to your "tab" widget and attach a ClickHandler to it to remove the corresponding tab from the top panel. This is basic GWT - you don't need an outside library for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the gxt  [advanced tabs example](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3aadvancedtabs) and the [gxt overview](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/)

It is gpl3, but that said it is more like Android where the actual development is behind closed doors unless you have a support contract, and then the src code is available when a version is released.

There are some exceptions available if you have a FLOSS project that is not compatible with GPL3 -- say for example your project is under an Apache license but you want to include gxt (of course, the gxt portion of the code must still comply with gpl3 requirements)

[gxt license](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/license/)